# MS Access 2007 : Spurious (?) "Database engine cannot find a record in the table..."

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a continuous form (Form X) that displays the rows from a table (Table A). On Dbl-Click on a row, a separate form (Form Y) allows modification of the associated row. This separate form has a sub-form to allow entry of child table (Table B) data. There is a column with a constraint on table B pointing to the primary key of Table A. There may not be any rows on Table B for any given Table A row.

All perfectly ordinary so far. Now for the problem:

If table B is empty then I'm getting...

"The Microsoft Database engine cannot find a record in the table 'Table A' with key matching field(s) 'Table B constraint column name'

...after form Y has closed. If there are any rows on table B at all (not necessarily for the current Table A row) then there is no problem. I have not knowingly attempted to write a Table B row which does not have a Table A entry.

Interestingly, if I put a 'msgbox' (my usual 1st-shot debug method) into form X after form Y has closed then the problem goes away. I've tried trapping for form error 3101 in Form X to no avail. I've even tried dropping the constraint and setting the sub-form record source via SQL in the form.

It is all very strange and I've probably done something stupid but I can't see it. Any help from you clever people out there would be greatly appreciated - I'm that frustrated by the problem that just simulating a "msgbox" without the input would do!

Comment: I can't see the problem either (since I can't see your code).

Comment: Please see "[mcve]" as well as [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for writing a good question.

Comment: If I knew which bit of code was responsible then I may have a chance of finding the problem. The root of the question is "why does it only misbehave when the child table is empty?" and also perhaps "how come just putting a 'msgbox' which does nothing but wait for a response into the calling form solves the problem?" The problem is so nebulous that I'm afraid my question cannot be more specific.

Comment: **My car's "Check Engine" light is on.  Can you tell me why?**

Comment: Seriously, I'm not psychic.  I can't tell you why your code is misbehaving without seeing your code. Or if it's a query you're referring to: I can't tell you why your your query is misbehaving without seeing your query.  Or if it's a form... etc etc...Just like the ***"Check Engine"*** light, you could speculate, you could guess, but you wouldn't be able to give any definitive answers, anymore that me Googling myself.  (And besides that's not how this site works, see the [tour] and [ask] as well as [mcve]).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I've been as specific as I can. It is a really weird problem that I've spent ages trying to track down so as a last resort I was hoping it was something someone else may have come across. I'll continue banging my head against the metaphorical brick wall - no doubt I'll find the problem eventually or come up with a work-around. Thanks again for taking the time.If I finfd the answer I'll post a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much as it seems that this was not a very good question, my solution ain't great either. I do not want a child table record for every parent so I removed the parent/child link where the subform is inserted into the form and I was setting the recordsource for the child table subform when I needed a record.

Although I have done similar things elsewhere without problem, this seems to have been the root cause of my difficulty. I reinstated the parent / child link, removed my manual recordsource stuff and set the subform's recordsource to the child table. All I had to do them was manually handle the child table rows that I didn't want and things seem to be working properly.

indeed... a woolly answer to a seemingly woolly question.